# What is in Pai Mei's mouth when fighting with the Bride?

Tags: plot-explanation, kill-bill

I'm referring to the scene when they engage in martial arts fight (after the sword scene). Beatrix hits Pai Mei at the neck, then he smiles and it seems he throws something to her. Anyway, something from his mouth is coming out. This always bugged me off, seeing the movie again triggered this question.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? Link the scene on YouTube or something.

Comment: You can see it here - 6:00 minutes.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VtfqAym5sQ   It looks like a white paperclip, but that doesn't make any sense.   If I was to guess, it was a movie error.

Comment: It looks like something he spits at her.

Comment: @GustavoGabriel yeah, it seems. But what is it?

Comment: There does not appear to be an answer to this. It's not mentioned in the script or anywhere else I can find.

Comment: It is probably a bone from his throat which he dislocated to be able to hit her back with his throat.

Comment: Interesting; I had always misinterpreted that moment as him using his neck strength to simply flex his neck and break the hold she had on it, but now I see that he's actually spitting the object at her.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like a piece of white lotus, which might be allusion to "Fist of the White Lotus", 1980 movie in which Pai Mei first gets his invincible status. More details about that movie [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080905/). I can't be certain, it is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: This might be a good answer with more detail.    It seems, Pei Mei is taken from the white lotus in the movie you mention and the actor who plays Pei Mei was in that movie as well, but didn't play that role.  (the movie is from 1980 so he was much younger).   Could it be a reference to that movie?    Maybe.   https://i.ytimg.com/vi/g-h15nTUaSg/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: But why showing her the lotus petal? I mean, it's like a secret or so... And, anyway, there is no point on "spitting" the petal to Beatrix face.